# (potential) Problem in proving an identity involving a Fourier series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Hi I'm having trouble with this question where it asks me to evaluate a fourier series at a particular value to derive an identity. The question is:

"Let $f(x)$ is given by
$f(x) = x$, for $0\leq x \leq \pi$.
The function is then defined on the interval $-3\pi\leq x \leq 3\pi$ by extending it as an even
function. It is then defined on the whole real line by extending it as an $2π$-periodic
function.

a)Sketch the graph of $f(x)$ between $−3π$ and $3π$

b)Calculate the Fourier series of $f(x)$.

c)By evaluating the Fourier series of $f(x)$ at $x = 0$ show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}"$$

So the first question was easy enough it looks similar to a triangular wave with its minimum at $x=0$.

For the second question I got used the fourier series even extensions to get the fouier series for $f(x)$. 
The fourier series I got was:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{2((-1)^m-1)}{m^2\pi}cos(mx) = x$$

For the third question I set $x=0$ and rearranged the FS above to get:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}+1}{m^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
At this point I was unsure so I let $m=2k-1$. This gave me:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2k}+1}{(2k-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

noting that $(-1)^{2k}$ is $1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$. Which is the desired result.

The only part that i'm unsure about is the part where I let $m=2k-1$ because I am usually quite poor at changing the limits of a summation.

Any verification/ help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct except for the part where you simply let $m=2k-1$. Instead you should write:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}+1}{m^2} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^{2k}+1}{(2k-1)^2}+\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}+1}{(2k)^2}\right],
$$
effectively summing separately over odd and even $m$ (which together form the complete set of positive integers).

Do you see now how the result follows?

Comment: Can't you then just say that the second term in the sum is always zero so your only left with the first term then carry on from there.

Comment: Of course one can say in words that all even terms of the series are zero. The important point here is that it has nothing to do with alleged changing the limits of summation.